# Android Studio most relevant architecture (Activity/Fragment, ViewModel)

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, mvvm, architecture

I am beginner and coding an app where there are menus, accessible through an Activity "Dashboard". These menus are related : for example there are database that we complete in menu A and which we use in menus B and C. I have some questions, because I haven't read things useful for me... :

1. Do I have to use Activity or Fragment for my menus ? Knowing that when we enter a menu, there will be different sub-menus proposed, and that menus are related
2. About ViewModel : how will they be useful in my case (for example, will my databases be lost if I rotate the screen without ViewModel) ? If my menus are Activities, do I have to associate them ViewModel, or are those only for Fragments ? I'm a bit lost ...  Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Read your full post, tried to understand and as per as I understood, trying to answer as follows.

1. From your use case, you should use Activity to contain the main dashboard and use fragments for other menus.
2. About viewmodel, when you are not using viewmodel with your data, if before rotation you didn't save those data somewhere (i.e database), then those data will be lost. But, if you saved your data in database then you can retrieve those data after rotation and re-use in your views. But, preferred way is to use viewmodel here, as your viewmodel can be the primary store for your data. Viewmodels are not only meant for fragments it can be used for activities too.

Comment: 1. I thought that Fragments were used to display multiple elements on big screens (for example to display a list on the left, and items on the right). If I follow your advice, I would only have 1 Activity in my app (the first page, which is a dashboard), and 25 fragments for example... Is that realistic ? Isn't it better to have 1 Activity for the dashboard, 1 activity per menu (there are 8 menus), and fragments for sub-menus and other pages ?

Comment: 2. I have already coded a database, without saving anything in my Viewmodel, but when I type something in a new item, if I rotate the screen without saving th item in the database, what I have typed isn't lost.. So what will be changed with a Viewmodel, if I already don't lose what I have typed when the screen is rotated  ? Thank you